# Spark - Reading many small parquet files gets status of each file before hand

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have hundreds of thousands of smaller parquet files I'm attempting to read in with Spark on a regular basis. My application runs, but before the files are read in using the executor nodes, the driver node appears to be getting the status of each individual file. I read into it a bit and this is necessary to infer the schema and partitions. I tried providing them as so:

```
sparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(
  DataSource
    .apply(
      sparkSession,
      paths = paths, // List of thousands of parquet files in S3
      partitionColumns = Seq("my_join_column"),
      userSpecifiedSchema = Some(schema),
      className = "parquet",
      options = Seq().toMap
    )
    .resolveRelation(checkFilesExist = false)
)
```

But even when providing the schema and partition columns, it takes a while before hand. After looking into the `resolveRelation` code a bit, it looks like it still has to query the status of each file in order to build an `InMemoryFileIndex`.

Is there any way to get around this issue?

I'm using spark-sql `2.3.1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no good way to avoid this problem in the current Spark architecture.

A while back I collaborated with some Spark committers on a `LazyBaseRelation` design that can delay discovering file information until the number of partitions--as opposed to just the schema--of a data source must be known, which isn't technically necessary until an action has to be run, but we never completed the work. Even then, when the time comes to execute an action, you'd take the hit.

There are four practical approaches to speeding the initial file discovery:

1. Use a large cluster, as some aspects of file discovery are distributed. In some environments you can scale a cluster down once discovery is complete.
2. Do the initial discovery *before* you need to use the data, in order to, hopefully, have it available by the time you need it. We have petabytes of data in millions of large Parquet files with three levels of partitioning. We use a scheduled job to refresh the in-memory file index.
3. If you are on Databricks, use Delta's `OPTIMIZE` to coalesce the small Parquet files into fewer, larger ones. Note that Delta costs extra.
4. Implement the equivalent of `OPTIMIZE` by yourself, rewriting subsets of the data. Whether you can do this easily or not depends on access patterns: you have to think about idempotence and consistency.

Once initial discovery is done, caching the in-memory file list is your best friend. There are two ways of doing it:

- Use the metastore, by registering your data as an external table. Whether you can do this easily or not depends on data update patterns. If the data is naturally partitioned you can add partitions using DDL and you can easily implement strategy (4) above.
- Build your own table manager. This is what we did as the metastore implementation had unacceptable restrictions on schema evolution. You'd have to decide on scoping: driver/JVM-and `SparkSession` are the two obvious choices.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this response! It's interesting that you mentioned the discovery can be distributed, because looking at the utilization graphs on AWS EMR, it looks like the hours before the actual reading of the parquet files takes place, the cluster is very under utilized and most of the nodes are essentially sitting idle.